# How to get unique objects from array of objects by all properties?

Tags: lodash

Given this typescript code using lodash:

```
import * as _ from "lodash/fp";

const range = _.range(0, 1000);
let objects = _.uniq(range.map((i) => {
    let foo = "foo";
    let bar = "bar";

    if (i < 5) {
        foo += i.toString(10);
    }

    if (i > 995) {
        bar += i.toString(10);
    }

    return {
        foo,
        bar,
    };
}));
```

I was expecting to only see the object

```
{
    "foo": "foo",
    "bar": "bar"
}
```

once and the total 10 elements with uniq `bar` and `foo` strings.

Expected output:

```
[
    {
        "foo": "foo0",
        "bar": "bar"
    },
    {
        "foo": "foo1",
        "bar": "bar"
    },
    {
        "foo": "foo2",
        "bar": "bar"
    },
    {
        "foo": "foo3",
        "bar": "bar"
    },
    {
        "foo": "foo4",
        "bar": "bar"
    },
    {
        "foo": "foo",
        "bar": "bar"
    },
    {
        "foo": "foo",
        "bar": "bar996"
    },
    {
        "foo": "foo",
        "bar": "bar997"
    },
    {
        "foo": "foo",
        "bar": "bar998"
    },
    {
        "foo": "foo",
        "bar": "bar999"
    }
]
```

Yet in reality I see all the elements to be kept in the list. It's as if the `_.uniq` isn't doing anything.

I want to get a unique list of the array based on identity / equalness. All array duplicates for all properties combination shall be removed.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I'm using [`lodash/fp`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide). If you use [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15), the order of the args of `_.uniqWith` are switched.

---

When you want uniqueness for an object you can use [`_.uniqWith`](https://gist.github.com/jfmengels/6b973b69c491375117dc#_uniqwithcomparator-array):

```
const withoutDupes = _.uniqWith(_.isEqual, objects);
console.log(
    JSON.stringify(withoutDupes, null, 4),
);
```

As to your first appraoch, keep in mind that `_.uniq` isn't working on a collection of objects but only works for simple arrays, e.g.:

```
const simpleArray = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3];
console.log(_.uniq(simpleArray));
```

outputs:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```